# Update BottomNavigationVIew menu cause flickers

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview

i have application where one (MainActivity) is container for 3 fragments, the hierarchy is for example like this : City -> Street -> House, each of the fragments is placed on top of the previous and in the bottom i have one BottomNavigationView which get inflated with menus for each fragment.
When i receive `onBackStackChanged()` i check which fragment is currently is the visible and update the menu.

```
    @Override
  public void updateBottomNavMenu(int menuResourceId) {
    bottomNavView.getMenu().clear();
    bottomNavView.inflateMenu(menuResourceId);
  }
```

The problem is when i inflate new menu it cause weird flicking animation.
How can i make it change menus without this animation?
I add gif to show the behavior.
[image]

Comment: Hi, I got the same condition. Any solution yet? Thanks! :D

Comment: @AndreaLk I couldn't find any solution for this and had to create custom views to show the buttons

Comment: Alright, thanks! Some workarounds what I have found is hiding the bottom navigation for 1s. Which give the Default Animation to finish, then I show the bottom navigation again. It's still not ideal though, but it helps with flickers. I'll let know if there's another solution. Cheers! :D